# Flutter : Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: json, flutter, jwt, mapping, httpresponse

In my flutter project, I have API request to the back-end server that return is generated JWT token with response body. The login API method requires the application to be giving API name, and parameter name (email and password) to the server.

The headers will contains the content-type: application/json and Authorization: Bearer -some token- .
While, the JSON body need to be in this form :

```
{
 "name":"generateToken",
 "param":{
    "email":"afifzuhair@gmail.com",
    "pass":"afif123"
  }
}
```

The login.dart code :

```
void _login(String email, String password) async {
setState(() {
  _isLoading = true;
});

var data, body, res, token;

data = {
  "name": "generateToken",
  "param": {"email": email, "pass": password},
};

// Send data package using Network class
res = await Network().authData(data, 'jwt-api'); //request

//response body
body = json.decode(res.body['response']);

//response header
token = json.decode(ascii.decode(base64
    .decode(base64.normalize(res.headers['Authorization'].split(".")[1]))));

print("Token : " + token);

if (body['status'] == 200) {
  // route to home screen when successful
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, routeScreenMenuAlt);
} else {
  _showMsg(body['message']);
}

setState(() {
  _isLoading = false;
});
}
```

the dart code i written is to form the json, but encounter error

> Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

It seems like my JSON encoding is wrong. Anyone know about mapping this?

Comment: In which line is the error?

Comment: @JorgeVieira this line -> `data = {
  "name": "generateToken",
  "param": {"email": email, "pass": password},
};`

Comment: The map looks okay, i think the problem is in another part.